# Apply lines() to columns of a data frame/matrix; each line with a different color

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, line, apply

I am trying to come up with a solution that doesn't involve using other packages such as ggplot. While plotting multiple lines is pretty straightforward, I haven't figured out a way to apply different values of an argument - e.g., different colors - to different lines. The code below (with the resulting plot) was my attempt, which obviously didn't do what I would like it to do. I also don't want to use a loop because I am trying to make my script as simple as possible.

```
df = cbind(sort(rnorm(10)), sort(rnorm(10,-2)), sort(rlnorm(10)))
plot(0, xlim = c(1,10), ylim=range(df), type="n")
apply(df, 2, lines, type="b", col = c("red", "blue", "black"))
```

[image: Plot generated using the code above]
What I really want is a plot like below:

```
plot(0, xlim = c(1,10), ylim=range(df), type="n")
color = c("red","blue","black")
for(i in 1:3){
    lines(1:10, df[,i], type = "b", col=color[i])
}
```

[image: The desired plot]
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `matplot()`:

```
df <- cbind(sort(rnorm(10)), sort(rnorm(10,-2)), sort(rlnorm(10)))
matplot(df, type="b", lty=1, pch=1, col=c("blue", "red", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Does it allow the same level of customization as plot()/lines()? Anyway, I will play with this function a bit. Thanks!